# How to convert a string to an unique numeric value (BigInteger)?

Tags: c#, string, encoding, cryptography, rsa

I'm doing a RSA project in which I have encrypt and decrypt functions that gets a BigInteger value when called and return encrypetd or decrypted BigInteger value. I get the number to encrypt or decrypt from the user (from textbox) and send it to the proper function. This work good when the user entered numeric values in the text box but now I try to make it work for any string that the user gives (numbers, letters and special chars) so I need to convert the input string to a unique BigInteger value so I can decrypt and encrypt it properly. I tried to use UTF8 encoding and Ascii Encoding (convert the string to byte array, the byte array to biginteger and send the biginteger to the proper function). both didn't work well because I couldn't decrypt a message after encrypting it using the methods above and after I converted the bigniteger value back to string it just showed me alot of strange characters ("?" and sqaures). So how can I make it work and what's the best method to convert a string to an unique BigInteger?

thanks alot

p.s. I do the project in C#

Comment: We cannot solve this without more input (the required protocol and the source code). Furthermore, this sounds like a local issue that needs some local debugging.

Comment: Why do you want to implement RSA yourself instead of using the `RSA` classes? If you implement it yourself you'll need to implement OAEP padding and avoid side-channel attacks, both of which are easy to get wrong. If you get them wrong it'll appear to work while being totally insecure.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to make something like this?

```
string input = "hello this is secret message!";

BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

//Encrypt :)
var ebi = bi * 5; 
var encString = Convert.ToBase64String(ebi.ToByteArray());

//Decrypt :)
var ebi2 = new BigInteger(Convert.FromBase64String(encString));         
var dbi = ebi2 / 5; 

string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dbi.ToByteArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Youd could use the [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268287.aspx) Datatype to store large numbers.The static TryParse method converts a string  to a Arbitrarily largenumber.

```
Using System.Numerics
BigInteger number;
BigInteger.TryParse("4565653454454544423", out number);
```

Comment: I already use the BigInteger datatype and I send it to encrypt and decrypt functions. This works well when the input is "259327521" for example (I can encrypt and decrypt such inputs), however this doesn't work when the input has letters or special chars "hello this is secret message!" so what I tried to do is to convert this kind of string to the BigInteger (using UTF8 encoding and Ascii encoding) but with no success because I couldn't decrypt properly a cipher after encrypting it and also I got weird chars after trying to convert the BigInteger back to the string.

Comment: can you post the code that converts the non numeric string